# Swift 2.0 NSJSONSerialization fails if response has only one item

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData
(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? [NSDictionary] else {
                    throw HttpError.ParsingFailed
                }
                completionHandler(success: true, data:json, error: nil)
            }
            catch HttpError.ParsingFailed {
...
```

It works fine, if the response data has more than one element.
However the NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData fails (goes in the else block which throws the exception), if there is only one item in the response.
Why doesn't it still parse the response in this case, and returns an array with one element inside?
How should be this problem generally solved?

Of course it would help to do an other parsing in the catch block with as? NSDictionary instead of as? [NSDictionary], but I would avoid this when possible.

**EDIT:**
object to be parsed which works:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "idConsumer": 12
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "idConsumer": 12
  }
]
```

and which does not work:

```
   {
    "id": 65,
    "delivery": {
    "id": 29,
    "idConsumer": 19
    },
    "postman": {
       "id": 13,
       "email": "testpostman"
     },
     "price": 89
    }
```

Comment: Please show the JSON data which you're parsing.

Comment: In what way does it fail? If `data` is `nil`, log `error`.

Comment: sure, I edited the post

Comment: Your 1st example of JSON is an array with 2 dictionaries. Your 2nd example is one dictionary with some nested dictionaries.

Comment: @rmaddy NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData fails - goes in the else block which throws the exception

Comment: That's because you are assuming you will always get back an array of dictionary. That's a bad assumption. Your 2nd JSON is a single dictionary. You need to code for that possibility.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, it's not possible to tell JSONObjectWithData to try to parse ALWAYS to a [Dictionary], even if only one element in the JSON? I have to write the logic manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because you are casting your JSON to `[NSDictionary]`. When you get multiple objects, you get an array of dictionaries, but when you get a single object, you get a single dictionary.

You should try to cast to `NSDictionary` if casting to `[NSDictionary]` fails.

If both fail then you should throw the error.